# Let Oracle delete parent row

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

For example I have an

```
TABLE child
ID      ... PK
PARENT  ... FK
PARENT2 ... FK

TABLE parent
ID  ... PK

TABLE parent2
ID ... PK
```

With an external API I am deleting the parent row and cascading the delete by the database, so each child is deleted as well. But I want the parent2 to be deleted as well. Setting to NULL or cascading the delete in the other direction is easy done by using an ON DELETE-option in my foreign key, but is there a way to do it the other way around?

I am using Oracle 11g

Comment: I assume that there can be multiple child rows for a particular parent.  And that you only want to remove the parent when you remove the last of the children.  Why wouldn't the "external API" that determines which children row(s) to delete also determine which parent row(s) to delete?  That seems like the most architecturally appropriate solution.  Or have the external API call a stored procedure in the database that determines whether to delete the parent.  If you must, you could build a somewhat painful set of triggers that would delete the parent but I wouldn't recommend that.

Comment: Each parent has exactly one child, there are also unique-constraints on the FK etc.. To be more precisely, the child has another parent and I am actually deleting *that* parent and cascading the delete by the datebase, so the child is deleted as well. But now the remaining parent is just useless garbage. I prefer to do the delete by the database to retain valid data in my DB.

Comment: @JustinCave why is it *painful* to do this via some kind of triggers? What could such a trigger look like anyway? Maybe this is a good solution for me?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it sounds like you can guarantee that there will never be multiple child rows that reference the same row in either `parent` or `parent2`, you can use a row-level delete trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER remove_parent2_row
  BEFORE DELETE ON child
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM parent2 p
   WHERE p.id = :old.parent2_id;
END;
```

Normally, you'd assume that a parent row could have multiple child rows in which case you'd need three triggers and a package with a collection in order to ensure that the parent row was only deleted after the last child row was deleted.

Answer (score 0):

you want to delete unused id(s) from parent(s) tables if they aren't used in child table. right?

you can simplly create a procedure to do this as fllowing:

create or replace procedure delete_unused_parents is

```
begin
  delete from parent p
   where not exists (select 1 from child c where p.id = c.parent);

  delete from parent2 p
   where not exists (select 1 from child c where p.id = c.parent2);

  commit;

end delete_unused_parents;
```

the next step is to run this procedure periodically and this can be done by creating a database job to run periodically(everyday, or ever two hours...whatever you want) which will call this procedure.

Comment: by the way this like "which came first, egg or chicken".